# What is Role Instance purpose?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I want to start using Application Insights in my microservice applications and I found this document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-config

So what I want to have is:
A name for my service (e.g. InsuranceCalcService)
A instance ID for my service if I have more of them (e.g. Instance1, Instance2 or a GUID)

So what I read from these doc is, that RoleName is the name of my service and RoleInstance is the Instance of my services.

So when I start 2 instances of the same service it looks like this:

[image]

This is problably fine, BUT when I open the Live Metrics, the RoleInstance will be used as Servername here - but is only showing once, even the service started twice:

[image]

So, what is RoleInstance? Is it my Instance key for a my service like I wish or is it the servername? Can I overwrite the servername elsewhere then the RoleInstance?